# No css/js on admin panel on live version, works locally on my pc

Tags: magento2, admin, login

On my live version of the website, On the Admin Login css/js is not loading, I don't have this problem anywhere else on my site. How can i solve this? on my local version on my pc it seems to work normally, I did

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

bin/magento, bin/magento setup:upgrade

cleared my cache multiple times but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Linux or windows platform ?

Comment: Please attache the console log error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the stores, for some reason there was a gb_GB store that needed to be compiled, by compile this store the problem was fixed, the login page was gb_GB instead of en_US

Answer (score 0):

The command you were running missing the theme and language code.

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend en_US`

Answer (score 0):

**Follow This Step :-**

> 1) rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/
>   pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache
>   var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session
>   generated/code
>
> 2) php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> 3) php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
>
> 4) php bin/magento cache:flush